# Show a message of user being locked out via custom code

Tags: community, sandbox

Is it possible to show a message of user being locked out?
I had a requirement : 
**If the session has expired and we click on any of the buttons, the page blanks out.**
This page is inline VF page.
Can we catch a hold of it in code?